# Oracle Timestamp Conversion with Dates

Tags: sql, oracle, date, timestamp

Assuming this has a simple solution, but I can't find it.

I'm trying to do some logic on a DATE field in Oracle. My desire is to take a DATE field and subtract X hours from it.

For instance: `SELECT A.MyDATE - 100 Hours from dual;`

however, I need a result in a timestamp format  'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm'.

I've tried `CAST(A.MyDATE as TIMESTAMP) - NUMTODSINTERVAL(100/24,'day')` however it didn't work.

I found out that the issue is that the MyDATE field when cast to a timestamp still contained some residual time elements. How can I reset these??

Thanks!

Comment: First, define "didn't work".  What was the result you got?  What was the result you expected?  When you talk about "residual time elements", are you trying to subtract 100 hours from midnight on whatever day `MyDate` is on rather than 100 hours from whatever time `MyDate` has?  What data type do you want your query to return? The query you posted returns a `timestamp` but if you're talking about wanting a particular format that implies that you want to return a `varchar2`.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. If MyDate was `2013-01-15` and I was hoping for to get `2013-01-10 20:00` as a result. I'm not getting this - I'm getting something like `2013-01-10 21:49`. I found out that 'MyDate' when converted to a timestamp hold hours and minutes instead of 00:00 in it - not sure why. SO... I'm trying to zero out the time portion of MyDate after timestamp conversion, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do this with subtraction:

```
select a.MyDate - 100.0/24
```

To convert to varchar:

```
select to_char(a.MyDate - 100.0/24, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

And, if you want to get rid of that pesky time on the date:

```
select trunc(a.MyDate - 100.0/24) as JustTheDate
```

Comment: You may want to add the to_char() that formats the result to your answer.  Up to you.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! One question, how do I convert the to_char output back to a timestamp in order to compare to current system date?

Comment: If I read the poster's comments correctly, they'd want to `trunc` the date before subtracting not after.  Otherwise, in the example they posted, they'd get `2013-01-10 00:00:00` rather than `2013-01-10 20:00:00` if `MyDate` was `2013-01-15 01:49:00`.

Answer (score 2):

The formats and dates in my example can be changed to any other formats and dates:

```
SELECT To_Timestamp(To_Char(Sysdate - INTERVAL '100' HOUR, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'), 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI')
 FROM dual
/

Output:

2/4/2013 10:18:00.000000000 AM


To remove time element add Trunc() to any of your dates...:

SELECT Trunc(To_Timestamp(To_Char(Sysdate - INTERVAL '100' HOUR, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'), 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI'))
FROM dual
/

Output: 2/4/2013


Conversion/Casting - when using other dates in place of sysdate then add formats as in my other examples:

SELECT CAST(SYSDATE AS TIMESTAMP) - INTERVAL '100' HOUR FROM dual
/

Output: 2/4/2013 10:26:35.000000000 AM


SELECT start_date tstamp_to_date, CAST(start_date AS timestamp) date_to_tstamp FROM
 (
  SELECT to_date(to_char(to_timestamp ('2013-02-07 10:07:47.000' , 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'),'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') start_date
  FROM dual
 )
/

Output:

tstamp_to_date          date_to_tstamp 
-------------------------------------------------------
2/7/2013 10:07:47 AM    2/7/2013 10:07:47.000000 AM
```

Comment: I guess true Oracle examples are too complicated for the user )

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, a `DATE` always has a day and a time component.  Depending on the tool you are using and your session's `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`, it is entirely possible that the tool may not display the time component when you look at the data.  But that is simply a display question, it has no impact on the actual data.

If you want to subtract 100 hours from midnight on the day that `MyDate` represents

```
SELECT TRUNC(MyDate) - interval '100' hour
  FROM dual
```

This will return a `DATE`.  If you want to return a string in a particular format

```
SELECT TO_CHAR( TRUNC(MyDate) - interval '100' hour,  'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mi am' )
  FROM dual
```

Note that I'm assuming that there was a typo in your question.  I assume that you want to display the minutes after the hour (`mi`) rather than the month (`mm`).

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to fetch the records which is older than 30 days (from Mod_date) and I am using the below query and it is returning all the data and I want only 30 days old data.

Sample :-  Mod_date    03-NOV-12 12.00.00.000000000 AM

Query :-

select Mod_date from fil_cnfact where Mod_date <= sysdate -30 order by Mod_date asc ;